# Automate Snapchat Web API

Tags: python, python-requests, snapchat

I am trying to just create a simple event using the new snapchat web api but keep getting error 401, unauthorized.

```
header = {
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
    "content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    "authorization": #####
}

json = {
  "event_name": "WEB_PAGE_OPEN",
  "canonical_url": "web.snapchat.com",
  "query_parameters": "",
  "device_screen_width": 1536,
  "device_screen_height": 864,
  "client_ts": 1663649806.927,
  "connection_download_bandwidth_bps": 10485760,
  "user_agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
  "locale": "en-US",
  "os_type": "WINDOWS",
  "os_version": "WINDOWS",
  "app_type": "WEB_DESKTOP",
  "app_build": "",
  "app_version": "11.95.0",
  "browser": "Chrome",
  "browser_version": "105.0.0.0",
  "domain": "web.snapchat.com",
  "referrer": "https://accounts.snapchat.com",
  "client_id": ######,
  "session_id": ####,
  "app_startup_type": "WARM",
  "user_guid": ####,
  "log_queue_name": "w",
  "log_queue_sequence_id": 51
}




r = requests.post("https://web.snapchat.com/web-analytics-v2/web/events", headers=header, json=json)
```

I can't find any code on the web as the snapchat web version was only released a week ago but if anyone has experience with this or know why it isn't working that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The beginning of your code seems to be missing, is that your request to the oauth server you are are trying to show?
If you are getting 401 either the auth failed or you are calling an end point which you do not have access to. From what you have shown I can't tell which.

Comment: Fixed, all that was missing though was ```header = {```